# Trouble setting up OpenSSH server on Windows 7 (can't start SSHD)

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, openssh, sshd

I just downloaded Cygwin for Windows 7.  I want to install an OpenSSH SSH daemon, and after running "ssh-host-config", I tried starting the service by running

```
$net start sshd
System error 1069 has occurred.

The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

I changed the password for user "sshd" to have upper/lower case letters and numbers.  But I still get this error.  Any help or additional troubleshooting advice is appreciated, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. If you had previously tried to install openssh you need to remove it first.I followed this these two links for removing openssh:

http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/vista-cygwin.txt

http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/

They are mostly the same although the first link is based on the second one and the second one has some extra information about installing privileges for users.

After that you can try to reinstall openssh it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your password for the cyg_server user has expired. This is usually the case with Windows Server versions.

Run lusrmgr.svc and change the password for it. You can also disable the Password never expires by checking the user's properties.

You should be able to verify the password did expire by checking the windows events.

Answer (score -3):

"1069 Error Code is caused in one way or another by misconfigured system files in your windows operating system."

You need to restore your OS to a previous state or download the repair tool. I have the same issue for the same reason.